# Meet some problem when i initialize a variable in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

**val holder:ViewHolder  //<-the  holder isn't  initialized and there is no error happen in this line ?**

```
package adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import bean.Planet
import com.example.list_view.R

class PlanetAdapter(private val context: Context, private val planetList: MutableList<Planet>) : BaseAdapter(){
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any =planetList[position]
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long =position.toLong()
    override fun getCount(): Int =planetList.size
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var view=convertView
        val holder:ViewHolder  //<-the holder is not initialized and there is no error happen in this line ?
        if(convertView==null){
            view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout,parent,false)
            holder=ViewHolder()
            holder.ll_item=view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_item)
            holder.iv_icon=view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_icon)
            holder.tv_name=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_name)
            holder.tv_desc=view.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc) as TextView
            view.tag=holder
        }else{
            holder= view!!.tag as ViewHolder
        }
        val planet=planetList[position]
        holder.ll_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        holder.iv_icon.setImageResource(planet.image)
        holder.tv_name.text=planet.name
        holder.tv_desc.text=planet.desc
        return view!!

    }
    inner class ViewHolder{
        lateinit var ll_item:LinearLayout
        lateinit var iv_icon:ImageView
        lateinit var tv_name:TextView
        lateinit var tv_desc:TextView
    }
}
```

**Why i declare a value or a variable in kotlin in the class that must be initialized,while that does't need to be initialized in member function in the class?**

Comment: please edit your question to include your code as text, instead of an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why i declare a value or a variable in kotlin in the class that must be initialized,while that does't need to be initialized in member function in the class?

In a function the compiler can guarantee if the local variable is initialised before you attempt to use it. In the code you posted there's the `if`-`else` conditional that initialises your `holder` in both branches.

A property on a class level needs to be initialised in instance init phase so that it can be guaranteed to be initialised before it is used. You can use `lateinit` keyword to leave it uninitialised and promise the compiler you're going to init it yourself before first use.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin variable should be initialized first, if it can store null then there is an optional type for this or you can use lazy initialization for some objects like views properties. Also you are using **val** which is constant and you can't assign it value later. so use var instead. You can use late init like this

```
    lateinit var holder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```